# Open pdf command in Nvim

Tags: filetype-tex, nvim, pdf

I use Nvim to write my LateX documents. In my init.vim file I have defined a command to compile my .tex file like this:

```
command CompileXelatex !xelatex -halt-on-error %
```

I tried to do the same to view the pdf generated by XeLaTeX,so i created:

```
command ViewPdf !okular %:r.pdf
```

but this doesn't let me continue to work in my tex file, then I tried:

```
command ViewPdf !okular %:r.pdf &
```

and

```
command ViewPdf !okular %:r.pdf & disown
```

and none of these options worked like I want. The last two didn't open okular and the first one locks the terminal until I close the pdf viewer, which is not what I'm looking for .

I want to be able to open the
pdf document on okular (or mupdf) and type in my tex file. I do not need it to live update (although if it's possible, I certainly would like), just
to open the pdfviewer and let me work on the source in Nvim.

And I don't want to install any plugin to do it because I think is not needed just to open a
pdf file.

Can you guys help me create this command?

(Ps. I do not speak english as my first language, so I'm sorry in advance for typos and strange wording)

Comment: Nope. it does not. I tried the way you've wrote and vim says jobstart is not a editor command. I tried the call command (i'm a noob, i'm sorry iif what i'm saying is nonsense )  with jobstart and it's says that :r ins not defined and that i used invalid arguments for jobstart (obviouslly since I pushed a undefined paramater)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!